# Change the color of a line with the change of values of X coordinate

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm drawing a simple line graph with 3 different lines in the same graph with Microsoft Excel. What I want to do is to change the value of each of this line with the change of X coordinate value. For example, when X=1-3 all the three lines should have the color green, when X=4-6 that certain part of the line should have color red. I am attaching one image to make it more understandable. [image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/conditional-formatting-of-excel-charts/  check that out..  I didn't read it myself but it could be promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As example that this can be achieved with (tedious!) hand crafting* but if it is the result desired the image might be a suitable replacement for the one in the question:

[image: SO16973439 example]

- Click on each of the lines in turn and Format Data Series, Line Color, Blue then double-click on each of the lines at each of the days Days less than 7 and select colour to suit (I did say tedious!).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a little less hand labor by splitting your data series into segments that span each of the periods you are interested in. The separate series will still need to have the line colors set, but you will not have to set the color of each data point.

It would be possible to take care of the color changes with VBA, but the hour is late for that little project

[image]